# Interpret bytes in a string as RGB in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I was wondering if this was possible.
I'm currently drafting a simple project that would **transform my text files into images** by using the **values of the characters** to determine the **RGB values** of the outputted image.

I know it sounds counterintuitive and no, I don't want to print a string into an image file, I want the text itself to determine the RGB values of each pixel. This is just a rough idea and is far from refined.

I just want a simple program that will work as a proof of concept.

Code so far:

```py
#first contact
from ctypes import sizeof
from PIL import Image
import math as m

def test():
    f='qran.txt'
    file = open(f)
    text = file.read()  
    file.close()            # this is dumb, should just read from file instead of dumping it into a 
    text = list(text)       #rudimentary fix, turn text into list so we can manage the characters
    size = m.floor(m.sqrt(len(text)//3))     #round the value for a square image
    print(size)
    # for elem in text:
    #     print(ord(elem))

    img =  Image.new('RGB', (size,size))
    pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map
    c = 0
    for i in range(img.size[0]):    # for every col:
        for j in range(img.size[1]):    # For every row
            pixels[i,j] = (ord(text[c]), ord(text[c+1]), ord(text[c+2])) # set the colour accordingly
            c+=1
        c+=1    
    img.show()
    img.save('qran.png')
        

test()
```

As you can see right now my idea is working as a rough concept. You can copy the [quran in plaintext](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peace-in-mind/Quran-Truth-Edition/master/English-Quran-plain-text.txt) and paste it in the same folder as this simple py program to see this output

[image: this output]

The image comes out as dull, since characters are converted into integers and their values are too high, and so most colors come off as light-dark gray.

Are there some libraries that could help with exaggerating the values so that they would come off as more representative? I've thought of multiplying by 10 and truncating the result of inverting the values then applying some filters.

I know its pretty much trial and error by this point (as well as polishing the actual code to provide usable functions that allow tweaking images without editing the function over and over again) but I'd like some outside input from people that have dwelved into image processing and such in python.

I apologize in advance if this post was too wordy or contained some unnecessary tidbits, it's my first post in this community.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you asking for style recommendations for your visualisation? There are many image manipulation libraries out there - asking for a good one is not what SO is for, you should try one and ask a more specific question if you can't get it to work as expected.

Comment: If you zoom in, the picture is actually pretty colorful.. The problem is that the picture is too dense and the resolution is too low.

Comment: look at the ASCII values of text. that is precisely the pixel values you get. the TOC is all upper-case, so that's lower values, while the rest is mixed case, mostly lower case, which is higher values. things are mostly gray (range of ~26 letters in 256), and the only color you see is from space symbols (0x20) mixed into some pixels. -- if you just want things to be colorful, you could generate a palette of colors (e.g. from hue-satuation-lightness with varying hue), with an entry for every letter you need (and numbers, and punctuation, and space), and then use that to paint your picture

Comment: Zoom in on the original image output (not the one on imgur) and you will see colors everywhere.

Comment: @MEE are you talking to me? why repeat yourself? Stack Overflow was offline for a bit but not anymore. you can post normally now.

Comment: @Grismar sorry if I wasnt very clear. I was asking for some ideas to make the output more colorful since alphabet values are mostly grey when translated to rgb. It was a bit late when I made the post and got a bit lost in my own thoughts.

Comment: @MEE I'm thinking of upscaling the resolution if it looks too dull but I'm a begginer in the field and this was just a rough proof of concept, I was more interested in making smaller texts into a more visual and colorful experience

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I couldn't edit my comment (comments cannot be edited after 5 minutes) to make it clear to the OP that I meant zoom in "on the original image" and not the one on imgur :-).

Answer (score 1):

Just implementing Christoph's idea in the comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import math as m
import pathlib
import numpy as np

# Load document as bytes
qran = pathlib.Path('qran.txt').read_bytes()
size = m.floor(m.sqrt(len(qran)))     #round the value for a square image

# Make palette image from bytes
img = Image.frombuffer('P', (size,size), qran, "raw", 'P', 0, 1)

# Add random palette of 256 RGB triplets to image
palette = np.random.randint(0,256, 768, np.uint8)
img.putpalette(palette)

img.save('qran.png')
```

[image]